# How to compare an EL expression against the result of another EL expression

Tags: jsf-2, el

I have following attribute in my Facelet:

```
rendered="#{createTicketBaseBean.show == '#{I18N['key_please_select']}'}"
```

I am trying to compare the value with property in my properties file, but I get following error:

> Error Parsing: #{createTicketBaseBean.show == '#{I18N['key_value_incident']}'}`

But when I replace the above expression with a hard coded value like below:

```
rendered="#{createTicketBaseBean.show == 'incident'}"
```

Then it works fine. How do I properly compare against another EL expression?

Comment: `"#{createTicketBaseBean.show == I18N['key_please_select']}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed invalid syntax. You can't and shouldn't nest EL expressions. You should see the `#{}` as one whole scope where variables can interact with each other.

Given your desired comparison

```
createTicketBaseBean.show == I18N['key_please_select']
```

this is the proper syntax:

```
rendered="#{createTicketBaseBean.show == I18N['key_please_select']}"
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC for explaining it and its really commendable for the amount of answers you give. Makes life for guys like us bit easy keep up the good work :-)